# Cloudkit database wiped clean before launching to App Store?

Tags: ios, database, app-store, cloudkit

I'm using Cloudkit with an app and plan to use the database to store and access strings and images. Before the app is launched from the App Store will the images still be accessible, or does the database get wiped clean? I know this is probably basic questions, but want reassurance before I put work into adding info to the database. I know there's 'development' to 'production' but want to make sure things aren't messed with in the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you move from development to production then only the structure of your database will be migrated. The data will not. So if you need data in the production database, then you need to recreate that data.

Comment: thanks, saves me upfront efforts to put stuff in. by recreate that data do you mean switch to production, and then adding data to the CloudKit dashboard?